# ASP / MS ACCESS check to see if username exists

Tags: sql, ms-access, asp-classic, ado

I'm creating my first project with ASP. This project is just making a basic login/logout with registration system. I was wondering how would I fix the below code so that when a user is registering to my website and enters a duplicate username that already exists in my database, it would redirect to the form with all fields still filled out but with the username field empty giving a message that the user already exists.

Below is my code:

```
<%
Dim objShop
set objShop=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

objShop.ActiveConnection=shop_STRING

objShop.Source = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName=" & Request.Form("regUsername")
objShop.CursorType=0
objShop.CursorLocation=2
objShop.LockType=3
objShop.Open

if not (objShop.EOF) then
    objShop.Source="Users"
    objShop.CursorType=0
    objShop.CursorLocation=2
    objShop.LockType=3
    objShop.Open

        objShop.Addnew
        objShop("FirstName")= Request.Form("regFirst")
        objShop("LastName")= Request.Form("regLast")
        objShop("StudentID")= Request.Form("regID")
        objShop("EmailAddress")= Request.Form("regEmail")
        objShop("UserName")= Request.Form("regUsername")
        objShop("Password")= Request.Form("regPassword")
        objShop("Address")= Request.Form("regAddress")
        objShop("Suburb")= Request.Form("regSuburb")
        objShop("Postcode")= Request.Form("regPostcode")
        objShop("ContactNumber")= Request.Form("regContact")
        objShop("CCCompany")= Request.Form("regCCCompany")
        objShop("CCNumber")= Request.Form("regCCNumber")
        objShop("CCExpiryMonth")= Request.Form("regCCExpMonth")
        objShop("CCExpiryYear")= Request.Form("regExpYear")
        objShop("CCCVCNumber")= Request.Form("regCVCNumber")
        objShop.Update

    objShop.Close
    set objShop= nothing
else
    response.write("Username already exists")
end if
%>
```

The error i recieved with the code was:

```
Microsoft JET Database Engine error '80040e10'

No value given for one or more required parameters.

/home/registration.asp, line 17
```

so I decided to put response.write("Username already exists") again in the if statement just before adding the values and then this error appeared:

```
Microsoft JET Database Engine error '80040e14'

Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'UserName='.

/home/registration.asp, line 17
```

I have no idea how I would correct this problem. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: [SQL injection playground ..](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) at `objShop.Source = ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need single quotes around your input in your SQL expression

```
objShop.Source = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName='" & _
                    Request.Form("regUsername") & "'"
```

Comment: now it says Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'

Object required: ''

/home/registration.asp, line 13

Answer (score 1):

Consider this pseudo code version of your current logic.

```
if not (objShop.EOF) then
    AddNew
Else
    display notice that user account already exists
```

**not (objShop.EOF)** will be True if you have one or more records in the Users table where UserName matches regUsername.

So what you're saying is this:

```
If we have previously stored one or more records for this UserName 
    add another record for this UserName 
Else (no matching record exists)
    display notice that user account already exists
```

Clearly you should not be collecting and storing credit card information.